# automatically update my activity to show which was written

Tags: android

Like you can see here, the user must provide a sim card number and when this number is provided, i would like to fill the content automatically by myself adding the sim card number which was provided.
I think that i have to update automatically (Autoupdate?) the activity or something like that. If anyone can help me by editing what i have done or by presenting a sample example, it will be very helpfull!
Thank you very much

The image of my application is here: http://imageshack.us/a/img199/1561/12216127.png

My code is here:

```
    public class RegulationTime extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       EditText edit2;

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.regulation_time);
       // Show the Up button in the action bar.
       setupActionBar();

       //Récupérer le n° de la carte SIM saisi par l'utilisateur
       EditText edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regedit1);
       String simCard = edit1.getText().toString();

       //Récupérer le n° du destinataire & le saisir automatiquement dans l'EditText
       String recoverRN = MasterNumber.getDefaults("mehmet", RegulationTime.this);
       edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regedit2);
       edit2.setText(recoverRN);

       //On rentre automatiquement le texte "#152#SIMCardNumber#" à la place de l'utilisateur
       EditText edit3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regedit3);
       String concatenation;
       if(simCard.length()>0)
       {
           concatenation = "#152#" + simCard + "#";
           edit3.setText(concatenation);
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having? Is there an error? Logcat?

Comment: @codeMagic I haven't any error. I have to update my application automatically but i don't know how! Like you can see in my activity, i have done nothing because i don't know how can i do this thing!

Comment: Explain more clearly what you want to happen, please?

Comment: @codeMagic Please go see the image of my application, you will understand immediately when I try to do. In the same activity, the user must to provide (via an EditText) a sim card number and i will show what the user is provided in an another EditText. In other words, i try to update my activity...

Comment: I did look at the image. That's what I needed was what you wanted to "update". You need an `onclickListener` for your `Button`. When you click it then you set the text

Comment: Okay thank you but i would like to "update" before this button is clicked. In fact, i would like to update when the user entered the sim card number via the first edittext

Comment: It's like autorefreshing my activity..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html). Use `onTextChanged()` so that as the user types in the "Sim card" box, the "content" box is filling up. So attach the `TextWatcher` to your first `EditText`

```
edit1.addTextChangedListener(new TempWatcher());
```

and create an inner class for `TextWatcher`

```
private class TempWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {   
         if (s.length() > 0) 
         {
             String sim = s.toString();
             edit2.setText(sim);
         }

    }
```

You will probably want to make your `EditText`s member variables so declare them before `onCreate()` then initialize them as you are in `onCreate()`. This should get you started. I wrote it quickly so you may need to tweak variable names, error checking if needed, and such. Let me know if that helps

**Edit**

```
public class RegulationTime extends Activity {

  EditText edit1, edit2;   // declare them here so they are member variables

 @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.regulation_time);
   // Show the Up button in the action bar.
   setupActionBar();

   //Récupérer le n° de la carte SIM saisi par l'utilisateur
   edit1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regedit1);   // initialize here
   String simCard = edit1.getText().toString();

   //Récupérer le n° du destinataire & le saisir automatiquement dans l'EditText
   String recoverRN = MasterNumber.getDefaults("mehmet", RegulationTime.this);
   edit2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.regedit2);   // initialize here
   edit2.setText(recoverRN);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but can you edit my code please? or write me some sample example please because I'm a new in android developpement

Comment: I'm working on a little example. There is the basics of how you would set it up

Comment: Okay thanx. If i understand correctly, i have to add TempWatcher class after onCreate class? But he didn't recognize edit2 in the class TempWatcher because he say: edit2 is cannot be resolved..

Comment: Create that class outside of `Activity` methods. It won't recognize it, that's why I said to declare it outside of `onCreate()` like right after your class definition...`public class YourActivity extends Activity{ public EditText edit2;`

Comment: I have done what you said but it didn't recognize edit2 too. I will edit my code to write my new code what you said me

Comment: Please don't edit your OP. You can add but don't change what you have

Comment: You need to keep the original post so that it is useful for others that may visit. Please change that back and I will tell you what you did wrong

Comment: No problem, thanks for fixing. Just want to keep the site functional. You need to put `EditText edit1, edit2;` BEFORE `onCreate()`

Comment: Okay thank you very very very much my friend, & excuse me for my faults. I'm new here & i think i have to be more attentive. But thank you very much, it was very useful!

Comment: I have edited my post. You are welcome. We all make mistakes but you learned from and corrected yours so all is good. Glad I could help :)