# Issue with EditText: doesn't work with multiple method

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm developing an app which will do multiple method in a single input. For example calculating square circumference and area, I give only one EditText and two button. But when I run the app, if I give an input and click the area button it won't do the calculation until I click the circumference button. And same goes if I change the input. Here is the code:

```
     @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.square);
    etSide = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSquare);
    tvResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSquare);
    Button btnCir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSqrCir);
    btnCir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            countCir();
        }
    });
    Button btnArea = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSqrArea);
    btnArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            countArea();
        }
    });
}

private void countArea() {
    try {
        side = etSide.getText().toString();
        s = parseInt(side);
        area = s * s;
        tvResult.setText("Area = " + cir);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops, you seem haven't enter the side length", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void countCir() {
    try {
        side = etSide.getText().toString();
        s = parseInt(side);
        cir = 4 * s;
        tvResult.setText("Circumference = " + area);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops, you seem haven't enter the side length", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Any better idea? Really need help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have your variables backwards. For example:

```
private void countArea() {
try {
    side = etSide.getText().toString();
    s = parseInt(side);
    area = s * s;
    tvResult.setText("Area = " + cir);  // <-- here cir doesn't have a value until you click the circumference button
} catch (NumberFormatException ex){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oops, you seem haven't enter the side length", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

So your `TextView` would display ""Area = ""

It looks to me like you want

```
tvResult.setText("Area = " + cir);
```

to be

```
tvResult.setText("Area = " + area);
```

Let me know if I'm not understanding you correctly

**Note:**

For your `Toast` you should use `this` or `YourActivityName.this` for `Context` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

One other suggestion I might make since your `onClick()`s only call a method, to make it simpler you could use one listener like this

```
public void onCreate(...)
{
    ...
    btnCir.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnArea.setOnClickListener(this);
    ...
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
     switch(v.getId())  // get the id of the Button clicked
     {
         case (R.id.btnSqrArea):   // call appropriate method
         countArea();
         break;
          case (R.id.btnSqrCir):
         countCir();
         break;
     }
}
```

You would just have to remember to add `implements OnClickListener` to your class definition. That's just a preference but worth mentioning.

Comment: Hi codeMagic, thanks for your advice. The TextView was just a little mistake I make, that's not the problem. But the real problem that I mean here is fixed with your onClick() suggestion. Do you mind to help me with other problem?? What should I do if I use two EditText which when one of them is empty it will show a message? For example the length and width. When user only input the length but the width is empty, it will show "You haven't input the width. Thank you very much...

Comment: You will want to use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) for that. You can set the listener on the `EditText`s and check length/values. Give it a try and if you have trouble understanding post a question with your attempt and let me know if you want. [Here's a SO answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566658/automatically-update-my-activity-to-show-which-was-written/16567135#16567135) with an example