# Instantly display text using EditText and TextView causes crash

Tags: java, android

I got hints from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18359811/how-can-i-instantly-display-text-from-an-edittext-in-a-textview)

And it seems that some people have used the same method and no one came to a crash. I have java file like this:

```
package com.example.instantinput;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText m_et;
    private TextView m_tv;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        m_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        m_et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
        m_et.setHint("please enter name");
        m_et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                m_tv.setText(m_et.getText().toString());

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

But it crashes during runtime and gives

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6015): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

right after I entered a second letter. Someone said the `setText` in `afterTextChanged` would give an endless iteration, so I put an if there hope it could stop this endless. Don't know what to do next. 
Thanks.
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et" 
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <TextView        
        android:text="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I just noticed the place of textview is "false"?

[image]

```
error from logcat right after the first input (of edittext):
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at com.example.instantinput.MainActivity$1.afterTextChanged(MainActivity.java:26)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:6568)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:6757)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextHasChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:897)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:353)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.change(SpannableStringBuilder.java:269)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:432)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:409)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:28)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:654)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:415)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:328)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:79)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
06-04 09:04:51.249: E/AndroidRuntime(10410):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It must be `m_tv` which is `null`. `m_et` is the view with the TextWatcher attached, so it can't be `null` on the second keypress.

Comment: @GrahamBorland if I delete that if(...), it would crash after any input, while the some others seem to use the same code but seeing no crash. Any idea why?

Comment: Clean your project perhaps? Sometimes the R.jave class can get out of sync if changes have been made.

Comment: I just noticed that in the app, right below the edittext, at the place of textview, it is "false"

Comment: @Tiina can you post all the error

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin you mean error from logcat? sure I can do that

Comment: @Tiina yes the logcat

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your crash is on this line:

```
m_tv.setText(m_et.getText().toString());
```

It must be `m_tv` which is `null`. (`m_et` is the view with the TextWatcher attached, so it can't be `null` on the second keypress.)

So, check your `activity_main.xml` layout file to make sure that the `R.id.tv` view is correctly defined. If it's there, do a clean build of your project in case something is picking up stale data.

Comment: Hi, did what you said. still no idea why it still crashes. I pasted the activity_main.xml too. Thanks.