# Android - Checking if editText is >3 before and after user input

Tags: java, android, button, android-edittext

I have some code where I need a "Create Account" button to be disabled if an editText field has less than 3 char in it.  If the User enters 3 chars, then the button should enable itself so that it can be used.

I have constructed the if else statement that disables the button if there are less than 3 char in the editText field, BUT on input, when the user inserts 3 char, it does not re-evaluate to see if the statement is true so the button of course stays disabled.

Once the user enters 3 char into the edit text field, the button should enable itself.

```
    Button buttonGenerate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOpenAccountCreate);
    userInitials = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUserChar);
    if (userInitials.getText().toString().length() > 3) {
                // Account Generator Button
                            buttonGenerate.setEnabled(true); // enable button;
                            buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
//Do cool stuff here
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {

                                }
                            });// END BUTTON
            } else {

                // If UserInitials is empty, disable button
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter three(3) characters in the Initials Field ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                            buttonGenerate.setEnabled(false); // disable button;
            }// END IF ELSE
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

This will be triggered each time the text in your `EditText` which has this `listener` on it has changed. You just attach the `listener` to your `EditText` like you would any other `listener` then override its methods and , from the linked example below, check the length

```
 @Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{   
     if (s.length() > 2) 
     {
         buttonGenerate.setEnabled(true);
     }
     else
    {
         buttonGenerate.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

You don't need to check in your `onClick()` then, just disable the `Button` by default and enable in your `onTextChanged()` if the condition is met.

**Rewritten**

The above could be cleaned up as

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {   
     buttonGenerate.setEnabled((s.length() > 2));
}
```

I also have changed it to `> 2` because I think that's actually what you want but the way you have it is a little confusing. You say "enter three(3)" which sounds like exactly 3 but your code looks different. Anyway, that's easy enough for you to change.

[See this answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566658/automatically-update-my-activity-to-show-which-was-written/16567135#16567135)

Comment: Excellent Job.  After a little bit of work I figured it out based on your answer.  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Don't you mean `s.length() > 2`?

Comment: Also, `? true : false` is redundant

Comment: @YoungCoconutCode yes, you are correct. Thank you, I've edited it to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Use an onTextChangedListener for the EditText to check the value and disable or enable the button.