# when EditText is empty and click calculateButton, app crashes

Tags: android

I have 2 editText (weightT and heightT)... my app crashes if I click the calculateButton... is there some way to disable the calculateButton if the 2 editText are empty?? or the user lack to input one of the editText .. or pop up message "Please input number"..something like that... Please Help...

Here is my java code:

```
  public class BMIActivity extends Activity {

         @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi);

       }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bmi, menu);
    return true;
}

public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {



    if (view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {

                }

        EditText weightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightT);
        EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightT);
        TextView resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);
        TextView categoryText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.categoryLabel);
        rGroup  = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rGroup);


    int weight = (int) Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
    int height = (int) Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());
    int bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);

    String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);

    resultText.setText("Your BMI is:" + " " + bmiValue + " " + "and you're");
    categoryText.setText(bmiInterpretation + ".");}


        private int calculateBMI (int weight, int height) {

    return (int)  weight * 703 / (height * height) ;

        }
```

Comment: Post your LogCat for the best responses.  It would be tough to figure out if you are having a problem finding a view, or its a division by zero problem, or there are some other issues as to why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press on the calculate button, check for the content of both the text fields. If one of them contains an empty string, you could simply return breaking the execution flow

```
public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {
    EditText weightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weightT);
    EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightT);
    String weightString = weightText.getText().toString();
    String heightString = heightText.getText().toString();
    if (view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {
         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(weightString) || TextUtils.isEmpty(heightString)) {
               // show error; 
               return;
         }
    }

     //... other code ... 
}
```

Comment: I was typing the same :-) ..but you are faster! I'm white belt :-)

Comment: hey guys... i tried your codes...  then when i click the calculateButton... it did not do anything... wow... i think this is it... thanks guys....

Answer (score 0):

> is there some way to disable the calculateButton if the 2 editText are empty??

Sure. You can use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) and disable/enable the `Button` depending on the length of the characters. [This answer has an example of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828050/android-checking-if-edittext-is-3-before-and-after-user-input/20828067#20828067)

> or the user lack to input one of the editText .. or pop up message "Please input number"

Sure again. This would probably be easier. Wrap in a `try/catch` and display appropriate message depending on the value of the `TextViews`. Something like

```
try
{
    int weight = (int) Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
    int height = (int) Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());
    int bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{   // display appropriate message (i.e. Toast)    }
```

Comment: Around whatever code would cause the exception. From what I can tell, you would be safe wrapping all of the code in your `calculateClickHandler()` in the `try` because it doesn't look like you want any of it to run if they enter invalid characters or none at all.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do this is to add textWatchers to your editTexts,

```
weightText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(weightText.length < 1)
                    (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourcalculatebutton).setEnabled(false);
                else
                    (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourcalculatebutton).setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

is one of them.