# How to check all the fields are filled in a login page?

Tags: android

I have put two EditText in my Login page. At first I disabled the login button.

I want to enable the login button When user fills all the two fields.

How to do it? Please give an appropriate solution...

Comment: using onfouselistner in android apply on edit text

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable and disable Button according to the text in EditText in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225245/enable-and-disable-button-according-to-the-text-in-edittext-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String text1 =editText.getText().toString().trim();
                if (text1.length()!=0) {
                  // Filed is not empty do your code here.
                } else {
                    editText.requestFocus();
                    editText.setError("Enter Text");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
           }
        });
```

Another way is to  `addTextChangedListener` to your EdiText

Like this:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
         enableSubmitIfReady();
      }

      @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
      }
    });
```

In that method, you should do like this:

```
 public void enableSubmitIfReady() {

    boolean isReady =yourEditText.getText().toString().length()>1;

    if (isReady) {
      yourbutton.setEnabled(true);
   } else {
      yourbutton.setEnabled(false);
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey Thanks.... i knew the Onclick Listener. It works when the user clicks a button. But i disabled the button initially.

Answer (score 0):

Use TextWatcher in android for both text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        validateFields();
    }
};
```

`validateFields()` method

```
protected void validateFields() {

    if(edt1.getText().length()>0 && edt2.getText().length()>0){
        btnLogin.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        btnLogin.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Inside `validateFields()` method, you can check length of input fields. If length are more than 0, you can enable `Login` button.